# Current list collapsible and parent elements selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having issues making my lists interact the way I need them to. 
I need to keep the functionality I currently have While adding in two more key parts. 
I have been unsuccessful at adding these parts without losing current functionality, or completely breaking the application. 
I need to be able to select/deselect all the children elements by clicking the parent. 

 I need the lists to be collapsible, and When a parent has a child on the second list I need the parent's name to be above the children on that list.

If all children are off the list on the right then the parent shouldn't appear there, however the parent should always be on the left.

The issue I've really been running into is that to make it collapsible I've been trying to use check boxes, and hide the styling, but none of that worked, and you'll see why. code below.

In summary

- Collapsible Lists
- Select/Deselect all children by clicking parent
- parent id appears on left list if 1 or more children are on it.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alphamalle/hb9j8ua7/)

HTML:

```html
<div class="half">
<ol id="one">
    <li id="alaska">
        Alaska
        <ul>
            <li data-id="alaska"><input type="checkbox"> Children 1</li>
            <li data-id="alaska"><input type="checkbox"> Children 2</li>
            <li data-id="alaska"><input type="checkbox"> Children 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="washington">
        Washington
        <ul>
            <li data-id="washington"><input type="checkbox"> Children 1</li>
            <li data-id="washington"><input type="checkbox"> Children 2</li>
            <li data-id="washington"><input type="checkbox"> Children 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="texas">
        Texas
        <ul>
            <li data-id="texas"><input type="checkbox"> Children 1</li>
            <li data-id="texas"><input type="checkbox"> Children 2</li>
            <li data-id="texas"><input type="checkbox"> Children 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
<button type="button" class="include">Include</button>
</div>
<div class="half">
<ol id="two"></ol>
<button type="button" class="exclude">Exclude</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.half {
display:block;
float:left;
width:50%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
$(function(){
$('.include').click(function(e){
    var $checks = $("input:checked");
    $.each($checks, function(k,v){
        var tempid = $(this).parent().data('id');
          var element = $(this).parent().detach();
            $('#two').append(element);

    });
});

$('.exclude').click(function(e){
    var $checks = $("input:checked");
    $.each($checks, function(k,v){
        var tempid = $(this).parent().data('id');
        var element = $(this).parent().detach();
        $('#one').find('#'+tempid+' ul').append(element);
    });        
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alphamalle/hb9j8ua7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Here is an updated demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/hb9j8ua7/19/**

Made few changes to .exclude method

```
$('.exclude').click(function(e) {
  var $checks = $("input:checked");
  $.each($checks, function(k, v) {
    var tempid = $(this).parent().data('id');
    var element = $(this).parent().detach();
    $('#one').find('#' + tempid + ' ul').append(element);
    var items = $('#two #' + tempid + '-2').children('li');
    if (items.length == 3 || items.length == 0) {
      $('#two #' + tempid + '-2-heading').hide();
    } else {
      $('#two #' + tempid + '-2-heading').show();
    }
  });
});
```

---

Here is a demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/hb9j8ua7/16/**

Something like this should do

#### HTML structure would look like this

I changed it a bit to accommodate collapse and checking all children.

```
<li id="alaska">
  <span class="parent">Alaska</span>
  <span class="collapse">collapse</span>
  <ul>
    <li data-id="alaska">
      <input type="checkbox">Children 1</li>
    <li data-id="alaska">
      <input type="checkbox">Children 2</li>
    <li data-id="alaska">
      <input type="checkbox">Children 3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

#### Include script

```
$('.include').click(function(e) {
  var $checks = $("input:checked");
  $.each($checks, function(k, v) {
    var tempid = $(this).parent().data('id');
    var element = $(this).parent().detach();
    if (!$('#two #' + tempid + '-2').length) {
      var ol = $('<ol></ol>').attr('id', tempid + '-2');
      var heading = $('<span />').text(tempid).attr('id', tempid + '-2-heading');
      ol.prepend(heading);
      $('#two').append(ol);
    }
    $('#two #' + tempid + '-2').append(element);
    if ($('#two #' + tempid + '-2').children('li').length == 3) {
      $('#two #' + tempid + '-2-heading').hide();
    } else {
      $('#two #' + tempid + '-2-heading').show();
    }
  });
});
```

When the include button is clicked the script will create a new ordered list based on the checkboxes that are selected. The new ordered lists under #two would look like this `#alaska-2`. This is achieved by

```
if (!$('#two #' + tempid + '-2').length) { // check if alaska-2 is present
  var ol = $('<ol></ol>').attr('id', tempid + '-2');
  var heading = $('<span />').text(tempid).attr('id', tempid + '-2-heading');
  ol.prepend(heading);
  $('#two').append(ol);
}
```

Apart from creating a new ordered list `#alaska-2` that script would add a span which would be the name of the parent and it would have an id like `#alaska-2-heading`.

If all the children are selected then the heading would be hidden which is achieved by this script (which is the same in exclude script too)

```
if ($('#two #' + tempid + '-2').children('li').length == 3) {
  $('#two #' + tempid + '-2-heading').hide();
} else {
  $('#two #' + tempid + '-2-heading').show();
}
```

#### exclude script

```
$('.exclude').click(function(e) {
  var $checks = $("input:checked");
  $.each($checks, function(k, v) {
    var tempid = $(this).parent().data('id');
    var element = $(this).parent().detach();
    $('#one').find('#' + tempid + ' ul').append(element);
    if ($('#two #' + tempid + '-2').children('li').length == 3) {
      $('#two #' + tempid + '-2-heading').hide();
    } else {
      $('#two #' + tempid + '-2-heading').show();
    }
  });
});
```

#### check all children

```
$('#one span.parent').on('click', function() {
  var checked = $(this).parent().find('input').prop('checked');
  $(this).parent().find('input').prop('checked', !checked);
});
```

#### collapse children

```
$('#one span.collapse').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need, but I was able to locate one issue. If all children are excluded the parent in the second list doesn't disappear. Also if all children from list one are included for some reason the parent in list two disappears, and can't be seen or used to select/deselect all the children.

Comment: can you please explain when the parent on second list should appear and when it should not. I think I am a bit confused about that. About the other issue I fixed it and updated the demo link in my answer

Comment: sure. The parent element should only appear on the second list if one of its child elements are on it. If the child element is excluded again, and there are no longer any children for that parent then the parent should detatch from the second list.

Comment: so the on list two, parent should appear if and only if there is one child ?

Comment: one or more child elements.

Comment: this is confusing to me because in your first comment above, you mentioned *Also if all children from list one are included for some reason the parent in list two disappears, and can't be seen or used to select/deselect all the children* So in that case if all the children are added it will mean that the parents will be hidden, right? Please correct me if I am missing something here

Comment: I apologize. I must have worded it wrong. What I meant for list two is if there is one or more child elements then we should see the parent above them. The select all is only there to move all children at once, and should not affect any logic other than that.

Comment: That's alright. So the parent in list two should also be able to check and uncheck all the elements under it. Am I correct?

Comment: please check this https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/hb9j8ua7/19/ . I made few changes to list two. Please let me know if that works.

Comment: this is perfect. Thank you. Sorry for the misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fiddle solution: https://jsfiddle.net/hb9j8ua7/1/

I'll explain the important bits here.

**HTML for single list item**

```
<li id="alaska">
    <span class="title">Alaska</span><span class="collapse">(V)</span>
    <ul>
      <li data-id="alaska"><input type="checkbox" /> Children 1</li>
      <li data-id="alaska"><input type="checkbox" /> Children 2</li>
      <li data-id="alaska"><input type="checkbox" /> Children 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I've added wrapped the title in a `title` span, and added a button to toggle `collapse` of the list.

**JS for include**

```
$('.include').click(function(e){
        var $checks = $("#one input:checked");
        $.each($checks, function(k,v){
            var $parent = $(this).parent();
            var tempid = $parent.data('id');
            var element = $parent.detach();            
            element.prepend('<span class="state-name">' + tempid + '</span><br>');
            $('#two').append(element); 
        });
    });
```

Refactored a bit to capture the parent in a variable only once. Prepended a span classed `state-name` to display the state name above the included children.

**JS for collapse and auto-select**

```
$('.collapse').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();
    });

$('.title').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').find('input').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Clicking the collapse button will open and close the sibling `ul`

Clicking the title will mark all children checkboxes as `checked`.

I believe this takes care of all the issues you were facing.

Comment: this is very close to meeting requirements, but has 2 issues. The first is if a child element is included it creates a new parent for each child as opposed to nesting all the children under one parent. Also if a child is excluded it takes every newly created parent from list 2 back to list one. Is there anyway to prevent this?